# How to append the .csv data into GeoJSON using Python

Tags: python, geojson, geopandas, json

The .CSV file has 6 indents, we need to append all the indent with GeoJSON file and updated file ready for open in QGIS

```
    import json
    import copy
    import csv
    import sys

    #print(sys.argv)

    def read_in_csv(csvfile):
    with open (csvfile.csv, 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        header = (f.next()).strip('\n').strip('\t')
        properties = list(reader)
        flatlist_properties = [x for y in properties for x in y]
    return flatlist_properties, header 

    def append_properties_to_geojson(csvfile, geojsonfile):
        data = json.loads(open(geojsonfile).read())
        data = copy.deepcopy(data)
        values_to_add = read_in_csv(csvfile)[0]
        try:
            for entry in range(len(data["features"])):
            data["features"][entry]["properties"][read_in_csv(csvfile)[1]] = values_to_add[entry]
    except:
        print ("Note: Your CSV and geojson features do not contain the same number of values")
    return data 

    if __name__ == "__main__":
    csvfile = sys.argv[1]
    geojsonfile = sys.argv[2]

    with open('updated_data.json', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(append_properties_to_geojson(csvfile, geojsonfile), outfile, indent=6)

    print ("Data dumped into 'updated_data.json'")

# Usage: python add_csv_to_geojson.py csvfile.csv geojsonfile.json

Error show

    ['add_csv_to_geojson.py', 'csvfile.csv', 'geojsonfile.geojson']
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "add_csv_to_geojson.py", line 37, in <module>
    json.dump(append_properties_to_geojson(csvfile, geojsonfile), outfile,  indent=4)
    File "add_csv_to_geojson.py", line 22, in append_properties_to_geojson
    data = json.loads(open(geojsonfile).read())
    File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in  raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: Possible to provide the CSV file and geojson file? Is there an ID column that exists both in the CSV file and geojson?

Comment: yes sure, share here for both.csv (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xrpw-r-5Si4QK8_Yb1AVB7Y6B1FzT6Ao/view?usp=sharing) and .geojson (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1P075lSevL9omAlXW325izfg_aDdwtk9y/view?usp=sharing) file

Comment: I want to join with ID column  name "state_name" common in both the files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend geopandas. [Attribute Join documentation](https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mergingdata.html#attribute-joins).

Here is how I would do it (Note: I haven't tried your data yet):

```py
import pandas
import geopandas

gdf = geopandas.read_file(...) # geojson file
pdf = pandas.read_csv(...) # CSV file

joined_gdf = gdf.merge(pdf, on="state_name")
joined_gdf.to_file(..., driver="GeoJSON")
```

Comment: Thank you,  Its works on shapefile only

Comment: Should work for geojson as well.

Comment: @snowman2....When I work with the geojson file the error shows "fiona.errors.DriverError: 'geojsonfile.geojson' not recognized as a supported file format."  can you please fix this issues to read and merge the geojson file

Comment: I just checked your geojson file and it is invalid geosjon. It starts with `var geoStates = ` and it is missing `,` in some places. Once you fix that, then it should work.